# Multiple Checkboxes in Android

Tags: android

I am designing contact list page in android in which it has an image box then Name and a Checkbox.When i select all contacts that are showing in screen and scrolled down for further contacts to select by doing this the contacts which i selected in previous page gets unselected automatically.
Here is My XML code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
    android:dividerPadding="8dp"
    android:minHeight="?android:listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/contact_image"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_user"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="@string/dummy_title"  />


    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="@dimen/standard_touch_target_size"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"/>




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So you want to keep the selected status of previous items when scroll back?

Comment: yes i want previous status@Leog

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the rest of the code, like the adapter? Are you setting somewhere the selected state for the positions you've selected? That's probably the reason you always get unselected checkboxes.